# How can I use removeCachedAuthToken to sign out users from my application?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been making a Chrome Extension and I can authenticate just fine using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(), it returns a token no problem. The thing is, I can not logout using removeCachedAuthToken().
During some research, I read that you cannot use it with launchWebAuthFlow, only with getAuthToken, but I need to authenticate in a third party website so I have to use launchWebAuthFlow. What are other options other than removeCachedAuthToken? I just need to drop a specific token that I get from chrome.storage.local.get() so the user is presented with the authentication flow again.

Thank you!!

Comment: I realized that removeCachedAuthToken only works for Google only auth, because I'm using a third party website, I needed to use clearAllCachedAuthTokens

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might face this problem.. using chrome.identity.clearAllCachedAuthTokens worked for oauth launchWebAuthFlow

```
chrome.identity.clearAllCachedAuthTokens(() => {
                    console.log('Logged out!')
                });
```